# Write text with canvas (onDraw view)

Tags: android, canvas, view

I have this view (a color picker view)

```
public class ColorPickerOvalView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Paint centerPaint;
    private Paint paintText;
    private final int[] colorsArray;
    private OnColorChangedListener changedListener;
    private String key;
    private boolean trackingCenter;
    private boolean highlightCenter;

    private RectF rectF;

    private static final int CENTER_X = 120;
    private static final int CENTER_Y = 120;
    private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 39;
    private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

    public ColorPickerOvalView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        colorsArray = new int[]{
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
        };
    }

    public ColorPickerOvalView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        colorsArray = new int[]{
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
        };
    }

    public ColorPickerOvalView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        colorsArray = new int[]{
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
        };
    }

    public void init(OnColorChangedListener listener, int color, String key) {
        //super(c);
        changedListener = listener;

        Shader shader = new SweepGradient(0, 0, colorsArray, null);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(50);

        centerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        centerPaint.setColor(color);
        centerPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        paintText = new Paint();
        paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        this.key = key;

        float raio = CENTER_X - paint.getStrokeWidth() * 0.5f;
        rectF = new RectF(-raio, -raio, raio, raio);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, centerPaint);

        //write the text
        canvas.drawText("OK", 0, 0, paintText);

        if (trackingCenter) {
            int color = centerPaint.getColor();
            centerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            if (highlightCenter) {
                centerPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
            } else {
                centerPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
            }

            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS + centerPaint.getStrokeWidth(), centerPaint);

            centerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            centerPaint.setColor(color);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X * 2, CENTER_Y * 2);
    }

    ...

}
```

and I want to write "OK" centralized on circle, but my ok is staying wrong (don't centralized).
I need to let this text exactly at center of circle.

[image]

How I can centralize this text? and how I change its size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawText() starts drawing at the lower left of the first character in the string. If you want it centered, you first have to compute the size of the whole block of text and then offset your start position.

To get the size of the text, you can use Paint.getTextBounds().

Comment: @EmilyR did this help?

Comment: Really Helped! Thanks a lot. And to change the size I found this: `float txtSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        paintText.setTextSize(txtSize); @Peri Hartman Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear. You might take a good look at Paint. It has setters for all kinds of things, including text size.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the text by half of its width to left. This means:

```
float textWidth = paintText.measureText(timeText);
float xOffset = textWidth / 2;
canvas.drawText("OK", -xOffset, 0, paintText);
```